# What is the difference between the MBA and EMBA?

Tags: masters, coursework, degree

Somewhere I found Executive MBA degree program. How this program is different from regular Master of business administration, and which one is better program?

Comment: Which one is better is an ill-defined question, because it depends a lot on personal factors. For the differences, Investopedia has a [nice comparison](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/022415/mba-vs-executive-mba-which-better.asp) of the two types of programs.

Comment: @Anyon, I'm not sure why you deleted your answer. The question doesn't seem to me to be a shopping question.

Comment: @Buffy I agree it seems more like a contrasting question than a shopping one. As for why I deleted it, well I can't decide if a link + short quote makes for a good enough answer. I don't really have any input of my own to add.

Answer (score 1):

Both MBA and EMBA are Master's of Business Administration programs whose learning objectives are identical.

MBA usually means full-time MBA, and EMBA is normally taught part-time (could be modular, evenings, weekends, etc).

However, there is a twist! There are two kinds of EMBA programs - just part-time versions of full-time MBA programs, which are geared for working professionals, and truly "executive" MBA programs, which seek to recruit senior executives and deliver their teaching globally, often in partnership with other leading business schools.

What's "better" depends on where you are in your career, what reasons you have for doing an MBA, and what mode of delivery works best for you in your current circumstances.